# WPF: How do I debug binding errors?

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm getting this in my output Window:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'ListBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')

This is my XAML, which when run looks correct

```
        <GroupBox Header="Grant/Deny Report">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding  Converter={StaticResource MethodBinder}, ConverterParameter=GrantDeny, Mode=OneWay}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Content="{Binding Entity}"/>
                            <Label Content="{Binding HasPermission}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was also going to recommend [Bea Stollnitz's article](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=52) but Jonathan Allen got his post in while I was still typing this one.  I also recommend the links in [this blog entry](http://wpfdisciples.wordpress.com/2008/04/04/debugging-in-wpf-wpf-disciples-tips-and-tricks/).

In this particular case you can see that somewhere a ListBoxItem has a FindAncestor binding to an ItemsControl that is failing.  That tells you right away there is a ListBoxItem somewhere that is either:

1. Not in the visual tree, or
2. Not under an ItemsControl (a ListBox is an ItemsControl)

In addition, you know that someone, somewhere, is binding a ListBoxItem's VerticalContentAlignment property to FindAncestor.

Looking at the system themes (shipped with Expression Blend and also available through NET Reflector's BAMLViewer Add-in), we see this:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
          Value="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" />
```

This explains where the binding comes from.  The next question is, how is a ListBoxItem being created that is not under a ListBox (or other ItemsControl)?

Some things to look for:

- Are you constructing ListBoxItems in code anywhere?
- Is there any ListBoxItem explicitly specified in your XAML?
- Do you have any code that manually manipulates the items in ListBox?

Hopefully this will head you in the right direction.

Comment: To your questsions, No, No, and No. The only thing that's interesting is that the ItemsSource is a data table.

Comment: But hey, at least you gave me enough information to know that it is in the style sheets.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem with the TreeView (though my data binding errors showed up as being Informational).

I solved the problem by defining an implicit style in the TreeView resource for TreeViewItem.  Within that style I defined the missing vertical and horizontal content alignment properties.

```
<TreeView.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" >
          <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
     </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Comment: I ran into this same issue and solved it using your approach. Thanks!