# If WPF binding path value is not valid, XAML code does not generate error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML and code-behind:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding _word}"
...

public class Word
{
    public string _word { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Above works fine.  But when I change `_word` to another name in the code-behind file, but do not make the corresponding change in the XAML file, I do not get a compile or runtime error.  The only clue is that the value in the `TextBlock` is not populated.

Is there something in WPF that will catch such errors?

Using Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition.

Comment: Are you looking in the "Output" tab of Visual Studio while the code is running?  It does not show up in the "Error List" tab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981566/wpf-how-do-i-debug-binding-errors

Comment: @landoncz You are right, it is shown there: `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '_word' property not found on 'object' ''Word' (HashCode=32790483)'.`  Thank you.

Comment: @landoncz Your comment is a more succinct and straightforward answer than the two questions marked as duplicate.  If you post your comment as an answer, I will try to accept it as long as I can do so for a closed question.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Sabuncu Thank you, and I agree. However, since this has been closed I can't post an answer to it...

Comment: @landoncz In that case, please accept my thanks.